# Gathering nonempty rows (POSIXct format) from diffrent columns for the same UserID in a single row

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, group-by, dplyr

I have a dataframe df with duplicate UserId where usually at least one row from corresponding columns A, B, C is nonempty.Columns A, B, C contain NA values and dates. My goal is to gather all nonempty (and NA if the entire column for that UserID is NA) rows for the same UserID in one row.

I've tried to use group_by() and filter() for nonNA values but the outcome is empty dataframe. I know that below code needs some modification to get the desired result, but could not figure it out.

```
library(dplyr)
```

### Example data frame

```
df<-data.frame(UserID=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,4,4,4,5,5,5,5), 
            A=c(NA,'2018-09-20 18:00:55' ,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,'2018-09-2018:00:55',NA, NA,NA,'2018-09-20 18:00:49',NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA),
            B=c(NA,NA ,'2018-09-20 18:00:42',NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,'2018-09-20 18:00:55', NA,NA,NA,'2018-09-20 18:00:49',NA,NA,NA,NA,NA), 
            C=c('2018-09-20 18:00:38', NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,'2018-09-20 18:00:40',NA,NA, NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,'2018-09-20 18:00:49',NA,NA))`    


df

UserID                   A                   B                   C
1       1                <NA>                <NA> 2018-09-20 18:00:38
2       1 2018-09-20 18:00:55                <NA>                <NA>
3       1                <NA> 2018-09-20 18:00:42                <NA>
4       1                <NA>                <NA>                <NA>
5       1                <NA>                <NA>                <NA>
6       1                <NA>                <NA>                <NA>
7       1                <NA>                <NA>                <NA>
8       2                <NA>                <NA> 2018-09-20 18:00:40
9       2 2018-09-20 18:00:55                <NA>                <NA>
10      2                <NA> 2018-09-20 18:00:55                <NA>
11      2                <NA>                <NA>                <NA>
12      2                <NA>                <NA>                <NA>
13      4 2018-09-20 18:00:49                <NA>                <NA>
14      4                <NA> 2018-09-20 18:00:49                <NA>
15      4                <NA>                <NA>                <NA>
16      5                <NA>                <NA>                <NA>
17      5                <NA>                <NA> 2018-09-20 18:00:49
18      5                <NA>                <NA>                <NA>
19      5                <NA>                <NA>                <NA>
```

### Code I've tried

```
df2<-df %>% 
group_by(UserID) %>%
 filter(!is.na(A),  !is.na(B), !is.na(C))
```

Currently resulting `df2` is empty

### Expected output is

```
df2

      UserID                   A                   B                   C
    1      1 2018-09-20 18:00:55 2018-09-20 18:00:42 2018-09-20 18:00:38
    2      2 2018-09-20 18:00:55 2018-09-20 18:00:55 2018-09-20 18:00:40
    3      4 2018-09-20 18:00:49 2018-09-20 18:00:49                <NA>
    4      5                <NA>                <NA> 2018-09-20 18:00:49
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `melt/dcast` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(melt(setDT(df), id.var = 'UserID', na.rm = TRUE), UserID ~ variable)
# UserID                   A                   B                   C
#1:      1 2018-09-20 18:00:55 2018-09-20 18:00:42 2018-09-20 18:00:38
#2:      2  2018-09-2018:00:55 2018-09-20 18:00:55 2018-09-20 18:00:40
#3:      4 2018-09-20 18:00:49 2018-09-20 18:00:49                <NA>
#4:      5                <NA>                <NA> 2018-09-20 18:00:49
```

---

Also, `gather` can take `na.rm` as argument.  So, the similar option in `tidyverse` would be (in addition to @Ronak Shah's approach with `tidyverse`)

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
   gather(key, value, -UserID, na.rm = TRUE) %>% 
   spread(key, value)
# UserID                   A                   B                   C
#1      1 2018-09-20 18:00:55 2018-09-20 18:00:42 2018-09-20 18:00:38
#2      2  2018-09-2018:00:55 2018-09-20 18:00:55 2018-09-20 18:00:40
#3      4 2018-09-20 18:00:49 2018-09-20 18:00:49                <NA>
#4      5                <NA>                <NA> 2018-09-20 18:00:49
```

NOTE: The `tidyverse` approach is only a slight modification to @RonakShah's method.  It was only mentioned as to show the similarity with main solution (`melt/dcast`).

Comment: Both solutions work, but melt/dcast solution works without any warning. In case of tidyverse warning is : '...attributes are not identical across measure variables;
they will be dropped '. Thanks!

Comment: @Imitation  Thanks, the warning is only because the columns A:C are `factor` class and they have different levels.  If it was `character`, there would not be any warning.  It is just a friendly warning.  Nothing to worry about

Answer (score 2):

We can `gather` the dataframe, remove all the `NA` values and `spread` it back

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  gather(key, value, - UserID) %>%
  na.omit() %>%
  spread(key, value)


#  UserID                   A                   B                   C
#1      1 2018-09-20 18:00:55 2018-09-20 18:00:42 2018-09-20 18:00:38
#2      2  2018-09-2018:00:55 2018-09-20 18:00:55 2018-09-20 18:00:40
#3      4 2018-09-20 18:00:49 2018-09-20 18:00:49                <NA>
#4      5                <NA>                <NA> 2018-09-20 18:00:49
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fill in the know values in both directions and then use distinct on the data.frame:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  group_by(UserID) %>%
  fill(A:C) %>% 
  fill(A:C, .direction = "up") %>% 
  distinct()

# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Groups:   UserID [4]
# UserID A                   B                   C                  
# <dbl> <fct>               <fct>               <fct>              
# 1      1 2018-09-20 18:00:55 2018-09-20 18:00:42 2018-09-20 18:00:38
# 2      2 2018-09-2018:00:55  2018-09-20 18:00:55 2018-09-20 18:00:40
# 3      4 2018-09-20 18:00:49 2018-09-20 18:00:49 NA                 
# 4      5 NA                  NA                  2018-09-20 18:00:49
```